# Adding Azure Authentication/ Google Cloud Authentication to Dash Apps

Tags: azure, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth, plotly-dash

For a very long time, I have been trying to add azure authentication to my Plotly Dash app. It seems that there is easy path forward.

I have tried integrating my Dash app inside a Flask app using , but that did not work as well as I constantly get this error:

`27.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2023 23:39:11] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash/deps/react@16.v2_11_1m1691986866.14.0.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2023 23:39:11] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash/deps/react-dom@16.v2_11_1m1691986866.14.0.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2023 23:39:11] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash/deps/prop-types@15.v2_11_1m1691986866.8.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2023 23:39:11] "GET /assets/custom-script.js?m=1691997716.3343513 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2023 23:39:11] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash/dash-renderer/build/dash_renderer.v2_11_1m1691986866.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

And since this integration didn't work, I cannot add flask based Authentication to my dash app.